# One entity in multiple schemas : how to switch schema on runtime

Tags: sqlalchemy

I use a database with multiple schemas (and the number of schemas is dynamic and not know at launch). Each schema stores the same tables definition.

In the documentation, I have seen that I can set a schema option to the corresponding schema name. But how can it work when the table is present in different schemas ? Is it possible to switch the schema name on runtime ?

---

UPDATE 29-11-2013
I found this http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName and I wrote the following routines to switch on the correct schema

```
engine = create_engine('db_host', echo=True)
dbSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
dbSession.configure(bind=engine)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
aTable = Table('aTable', metadata, 
                  Column('foo', String, primary_key=True),
                  Column('bar', String))

def map_class_to_some_table(cls, table, entity_name, **kw):
     newcls = type(entity_name, (cls, ), {})
     mapper(newcls, table, **kw)
     return newcls


class ObjectDefinition(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class ObjectRepository():

    objectMapper = {}

    @classmethod
    def _getObjectMapper(cls, aSchema):
        if cls.objectMapper == None:
            cls.objectMapper = {}
        mapper = cls.objectMapper .get(aSchema)
        if mapper == None:
            logging.debug('Need to create a new mapper for schema %s'%aSchema)
            objectSchemaTable  = aTable.tometadata(metadata, schema=aSchema)
            mapper = map_class_to_some_table(ObjectDefinition, objectSchemaTable  , "object_%s"%aSchema)
            cls.objectMapper [aSchema] = mapper
        return mapper    

    @staticmethod
    def loadAllObject(schema):
        return dbSession.query(UserRepository._getUserMapper(schema)).all()
```

Comment: You might find [Horizontal Sharding](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#examples-sharding) example useful.

Comment: I read the example but I not understand how I can switch schema_name on runtime with shards. I can switch differents sessions but schema is defined in metadata, not in session.

Comment: After some additional search, I found http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName (see my update)